# Find all instances of word occurring in a file followed by an equal sign and quotation mark

Tags: string, bash, find

I have a file that has the word system="Some Value" within the file and the file is 1 long line.

If the file was formatted correctly I know I can do something like:

```
cat filename | grep 'system="'
```

and I would receive them all line by line. But with the file being many paragraphs and 1 long line for each paragraph, I can't.

It would be nice to dump all the times the word system plus it's value in another file like so:

```
system="Some words"
system="Some other words"
system="and more"
```

Comment: please provide a sample file and its contents, along with the desired output

Comment: Hard to tell without input file, but `grep -o 'system="[^"]*"' filename` could work.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't shown us your Input_file, so I am considering that following is your Input_file.

```
cat Input_file
system="Some words" system="Some other words" system="and more"
```

now following is the code which will help us to take output as your shown output.

```
awk '{gsub(/ system/,"\nsystem");print}'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
system="Some words"
system="Some other words"
system="and more"
```

**Explanation:** Simply using global substitution utility of awk to substitute all the occurrences of string  `system` to a `newline system`. Then printing the line.

**EDIT:** Or with sed solution you could do simply substitute all space system to new line system as follows.

```
sed 's/ system/\nsystem/g'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Benjamin had the correct answer.

```
grep -o 'system="[^"]*"' filename > final.txt
```

Seemed to work great.

Appreciate the help!